# Optimal play in Strings & Coins

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Consider the following Position of Strings & Coins:

[image: Strings and Coins position]

(taken from Albert, Michael H., Richard J. Nowakowski, and David Wolfe. Lessons in play: an introduction to combinatorial game theory. CRC Press, 2019.)

Alice is to play next. The official solution states that Alice can win by "tak[ing]
both coins and then cut[ting] the lower-right string". However, Bob could then cut the upper left string. This would lead to Alice getting the four coins to the left, and then having to cut a string on the long chain at the right, which lets Bob take them. The end result would be a draw at six points each, but the book claims that Alice can win at eight to two. What am I missing here?

Edit for more complete Information:

The game of Coins and Strings is just Dots and Boxes drawn in a different format. That is, the player whose turn it is may cut one of the strings (depicted as lines in the graphic). If a coin has no more Strings attached to it the player who cut the last String gets the coin. Whenever a player makes a move that nets them (at least) one coin, that player must make an additional move.

The two coins referred two in the official solution are the fourth and fifth coin in the top row. Since the fifth coin is only supported by one string, it can be taken immediately. This results in Alice getting another move. The fourth coin has only one string left at this point, and can therefore also be taken, netting another move. For this move the authors propose to take the string in the lower-right.

Comment: Bob will at some stage cut a string on the group of five strings and four coins on the left.  Alice does not need to take all four of these coins: she can take two, and leave the other two for Bob, forcing Bob to give all the remaining coins on the right to Alice.  So Alice can get the initial $2$, then $2$ on the left and then the remaining $6$ on the right, i.e. $10$ in total (so Bob only gets $2$)

Comment: Thanks @Henry! That makes sense, the possibility of just not taking all four coins on the left somehow slipped my mind